# I want to use mysql cross join between examination tbl & Contineous Assesment tbl with a WHERE clause but it always turns to inner join

Tags: join

[examTable[CAtable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f3UgQ.png)I want to use mysql cross join between examination tbl & Contineous Assesment  tbl with a WHERE clause.
I want to get record of a student from both tables. I try left join exam on CA and it works but the issue is when the student wrote CA but doesn't have exam, his CA will not be counted.

I want to join the two tables so that it can count for student with either exam or CA or both.

This is my left join query:

```
SELECT examscore.stuid,
    examscore.subcode,
    examscore.score AS examscore,
    csscore.score,
    SUM(examscore.score + IFNULL(csscore.score, 0)) AS totalscore
FROM examscore
    LEFT JOIN csscore on examscore.stuid = csscore.stuid
       and examscore.subcode = csscore.subcode
where examscore.term = 'FIRST'
    and examscore.class = 'jss1a'
GROUP BY examscore.stuid;
```

The above query works only when the student has written the exam.
I try **cross join** but if i use where clause, it turns to inner join.

Please how can i achieved it.

Thanks

Comment: If you could please also include some sample data and desired results in your question. It's difficult to reverse engineer your SQL that isn't doing what you want to divine your table structure.

Comment: I have edited the post and added sample data for CA. the table structure is the same for exam.